# PHP: Creating multiple select dropdowns from MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create multiple dropdowns from mysql database using PHP.

Basically, all the data required for the dropdowns is in one Table in mysql database and in different column.

to explain this, this is how it looks like in the mysql:

table name: `drop_options`

Table structure:

```
id  sub_cat_name  op_name  op_value
1   apple         colour     red
2   apple         colour     yellow
3   apple         colour     green
4   apple         size       small
5   apple         size       big
6   apple         size       medium

etc etc....
```

so i need to create dropdown selects like this:

```
<select name="colour">
<option>red</option>
<option>yellow</option>
<option>green</option>
</select>


<select name="size">
<option>small/option>
<option>medium</option>
<option>big</option>
</select>
```

but with my code bellow, it creates 1 select per result and separate the options in different selects!

Example like so:

```
<select name="size">
<option>small/option>
</select>

<select name="size">
<option>medium</option>
</select>

<select name="size">
<option>big</option>
</select>
```

This is my code:

```
$drops ="";

$sql44 ="SELECT * FROM drop_options WHERE sub_cat_name='$currentproduct'";

$query44 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql44);
$productCount44 = mysqli_num_rows($query44); // count the output amount
if ($productCount44 > 0) {
    while($row44 = mysqli_fetch_array($query44, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $op_name = $row44["op_name"];
             $op_value = $row44["op_value"];



             /*foreach($op_value as $opval){
                 $dropsv ='<option>'.$op_value.'</option>';
             }*/

             $drops .='<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <p class="margin-bottom-zero">'.$op_name.'</p>
                <select name="'.$op_name.'" class="selectpicker">

                <option>Select</option>
                <option>'.$op_value.'</option>
                </select>
            </div>';

    }
} else {
    $drops ='';
}
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <p class="margin-bottom-zero">Material</p>
                <select name="Material" class="selectpicker">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option>450gsm silk</option></select></div><option>350gsm silk</option>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:
I have placed two `if` conditions below.

1.) `$op_name` is assigned a value outside the while loop to make sure a new dropdown `select` is not initiated when the `$op_name` is the same as the last one.
2.) `$first` makes sure we close the dropdown and div tags after each dropdown instance.

```
$drops ="";

$sql44 ="SELECT * FROM drop_options WHERE sub_cat_name='$currentproduct'";

$query44 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql44);
$productCount44 = mysqli_num_rows($query44); // count the output amount
if ($productCount44 > 0) 
{
    $op_name = '';
    $first = 0;

    while($row44 = mysqli_fetch_array($query44, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {


            $op_value = $row44["op_value"];

            if($op_name != $row44["op_name"])
            {
                if($first)
                {
                    $drops .='</select></div>';
                }

                $op_name = $row44["op_name"];

                $drops .='<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <p class="margin-bottom-zero">'.$op_name.'</p>
                <select name="'.$op_name.'" class="selectpicker">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option>'.$op_value.'</option>';
            }
            else
            {
                $drops .= '<option>'.$op_value.'</option>';
            }

            $first = 1;
    }
} 
else 
{
    $drops ='';
}
$drops .='</select></div>';
```

This code should work fine but just in case it doesn't, share your output and I'll tweak it a bit to make sure it gives you what you want.

Comment: This will create one select menu but it will only put 1 option inside the select.

Comment: No, it will check if the `$op_name` is the same as before and put the `$op_value` as option in the current select.

Comment: That takes place within the `else` section.

Comment: yes, I understand, but when i tested it, it will put one option inside the select menu and puts the rest of the options outside of it.

Comment: Could you share the generated html here?

Comment: Wait, there's a problem with the code, I missed a quote mark. Let me just update that.

Comment: Okay, this should do it. Edited my answer.

Comment: thank you so so so much mate. appreciate it. worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT sub_cat_name, op_name, GROUP_CONCAT(op_value)
FROM drop_options
WHERE sub_cat_name='$currentproduct'
GROUP BY sub_cat_name, op_name
```

And foreach loop:

```
foreach (explode(',', $op_value) as $select_value) {
   echo '<option>'.$select_value.'</option>';
}
```